# Count of already created entities of particular Prototype-bean in Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, prototype, javabeans

Is there any way to get **the number and some identification information** of already created entities of particular Prototype-bean in Spring application?

**Addition**. In our project we have more then 400 prototype-beans and I would like to trace the state what beans were created during execution and the number of entities of each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to **see the actual picture about created prototype-beans**.
I use free **VisualVM** memory profiler.

In the **Sampler** tab you can see all instances of created classes including singleton and prototype beans.

You'll see the names of your own packages and classes. In this case:

- **prototype** is a package with my prototype-beans.
- **singleton** is a package with my singleton-beans.
- **newclasses** is a package with classes that I created by **new** operator.

Also after the **garbage collector** will clean up the memory you will see the result here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by Publish and Listen Application Events.

1. create you own event.
2. when prototype bean was created send event from it.
3. create count ApplicationListener , and listen to income creation event.

here is example 
[Spring – Publish and Listen Application Events](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/how-to-publish-and-listen-application-events-in-spring/)

**Spring does not manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype bean: the container instantiates, configures, decorates and otherwise assembles a prototype object, hands it to the client and then has no further knowledge of that prototype instance.**

Simple variant :

```
public class PrototypeCreationEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private String beanName;

    public PrototypeCreationEvent(Object source , String beanName) {
        super(source);
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    public String getBeanName(){
        return beanName;
    }
}

public class PrototypeCreationListener implements ApplicationListener<PrototypeCreationEvent> {
    private ConcurrentMap<String,AtomicInteger> prototypeCreationStatistic = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    //or from guava AtomicLongMap prototypeCreationStatistic = AtomicLongMap.create();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(PrototypeCreationEvent event) {
        prototypeCreationStatistic.computeIfAbsent(event.getBeanName() ,  k->new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet();

        System.out.println(event);
    }

    public ConcurrentMap<String,AtomicInteger> getPrototypeCreationStatistic(){
        return prototypeCreationStatistic;
    }
}

public abstract class PrototypeCreationPublisher implements BeanNameAware , ApplicationEventPublisherAware ,InitializingBean {
    private String beanName;
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;


    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String name) {
        this.beanName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    }

    @PostConstruct //or use interface InitializingBean
    public void sendEventAfterCreation() throws Exception {
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new PrototypeCreationEvent(this , beanName));
    }
}

@Component(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PrototypeA extends PrototypeCreationPublisher{
}

@Component(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PrototypeB extends PrototypeCreationPublisher{
}
```

example :

```
    PrototypeA prototypeA1 = context.getBean(PrototypeA.class);
    PrototypeA prototypeA2 = context.getBean(PrototypeA.class);
    PrototypeA prototypeA3 = context.getBean(PrototypeA.class);
    PrototypeB prototypeB1 = context.getBean(PrototypeB.class);

    PrototypeCreationListener statistic = context.getBean(PrototypeCreationListener.class);
    statistic.getPrototypeCreationStatistic().entrySet().forEach(s->{
        System.out.println(s.getKey() + " count = "+s.getValue());
    });
```

result :

```
    PrototypeB count = 1
    PrototypeA count = 3
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get the information from ApplicationContext?

Comment: Ok. I'll try your way.

Comment: May be I don't understand something... but I can obtain the information about creating the bean by only printing the information in console from the constructor of bean. Please see my corrected question. In our project we have more then 400 prototype-beans so I would like to check what prototype-beans were created and the number of them.

Comment: Add map set list ... into listener. Listener is singltone. When event come into listener save it. Use you own event with iformation some information like type of been if you use many different beans prototype.

Comment: Do you need to know count only for one prototype class or for many ?

Comment: but , if you count only one bean class use atomicinteger as counter. if for many use ConcurrentMap as events might come simultaneous

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to collect information about the usage of all prototype-beans in our project. I need to get the statistics somehow without the correcting the existing code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146538/discussion-between-sbjavateam-and-kirill-ch).